# knockout select - how can i set a default value using 2 different observables

Tags: knockout.js

Hi I have a select in my view

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedInsurancePolicy">
                <select data-bind="options: $parent.insuranceCompanies,
                   optionsText: 'companyName',
                   value: $parent.selectedInsurancePolicy.companyID">
</select>
```

I am trying to bind the list of options to one thing and then the value to another.

The above is the latest iteration, but I have tried numerous options.

I basically want to do:

- List all companies and their ids as the value.
- Use their ID within a different part of the viewModel

**The problem comes in that I do not how to use my list of companies to populate the options but use the selected option to change my observable insurance policy**

I am guessing I need to create a computed of some sort but I am totally confused as to how I can achieve this 'cross-referencing' of ID's.

My viewModel is below

```
var insuranceViewModel = function(companies, policies){
var self = this;

var companies = companies || {};
var policies = policies || {};


self.EditableInsuranceCompany = ko.observable();
self.EditableInsurancePolicy = ko.observable();

self.selectedInsuranceCompany = ko.observable();
self.selectedInsurancePolicy = ko.observable();
self.selectInsurancePolicyCompany = ko.observable();

self.insuranceCompanies = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(companies, function (company) {
    return new observableInsuranceCompany(company.id, company.name, company.address1, company.address2, company.city, company.postcode, company.phone, company.fax);
}));

self.insurancePolicies = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(policies, function (policy) {

    var companyName = ko.computed(function(){

        var company = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.insuranceCompanies(), function(company) {
        return company.id == policy.companyID;
    })

    return company;
    });       
    console.log(companyName().companyName());
    return new observableInsurancePolicy(policy.id,policy.companyID,companyName().companyName(),policy.policyNumber,policy.expiry,policy.policyDetails);
}));

addInsurancePolicy = function(){
    return function(){
        totalInsurancePoliciesLoaded += 1;
        var company = new observableInsurancePolicy(totalInsurancePoliciesLoaded,1,"aviva","","","","","");
        self.insurancePolicies.push(company);
        self.selectedInsurancePolicy(company);
    };
};
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code necessary to reproduce the *actual problem* - you dont need that entire viewmodel to demonstrate the issue!

Comment: Your question title and body doesn't agree it seems. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I have attempted to reduce the viewmodel but all that was there was necessary really, I have adjusted the title too and added some clarification in bold.

Comment: It may be a language issue, but after re-reading several times, the **bold** question does not make much sense to me. - What doesn't help is that the code doesn't comprise an actual repro, it's just *parts* of it. Try to create a working Stack Snippet that exhibits *only* the problem you're asking about. (Add a little bit of code for that, but when you do try to remove other bits too: all those observables, address details, etc, are not needed to demo your issue I'd think.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedInsurancePolicy">
                <select data-bind="options: $parent.insuranceCompanies,
                   optionsText: 'companyName',
                   value: $parent.selectedInsurancePolicy().companyID">
</select>
```

NB `selectedInsurancePolicy()` with parentheses. As it's an observable, you need to call it to retrieve the value inside.